# Can't get Knockout to do a simple 'options' binding

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js

I've got the following simple setup in knockout

```
var data = { 
  'Divisions': [
    { 'divID' : '105' },
    { 'divID' : '103' }
  ]
};

var viewModel = ko.mapping.fromJS(data);

ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

and the following HTML that does not properly bind

```
<select data-bind="
  options: Divisions, 
  optionsText: divID,
  optionsCaption: 'Choose...'">
</select>
```

onload I get 'ReferenceError: divID is not defined'.

If I use the following binding, it works

```
<select data-bind="
  options: Divisions, 
  optionsText: function(item) { 
    return item.divID(); 
  }, 
  optionsCaption: 'Choose...'">
</select>
```

For reference:

[Working binding in jsbin, with the ugly binding](http://jsbin.com/aduqaz/1/edit#javascript,html)

[Non working version in jsbin that looks like it should work, with the clean binding](http://jsbin.com/aduqaz/2/edit#javascript,html)

I suspect that this is all being caused by ko.mapping.fromJS making every child in `Divisions` an observable, thus making it so that I can't simply access everything as a simple property name, but I just found a [similar example](http://jsfiddle.net/greenlaw110/Tkqqb/3/) that is doing the exact same thing!

Comment: ARGH, figured it out, stupid stupid stupid mistake

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You forgot the single quotes around your optionsText

```
<select data-bind="
  options: Divisions, 
  optionsText: 'divID',
  optionsCaption: 'Choose...'">
</select>
```

Comment: This was my issue as well. Even Intellij with javascript language injection for the data-bind attribute did not catch my object properties as invalid identifiers :(